# ERROR JS1015 - Unterminated String Constant

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, jscript

I'm running a jscript on Microsoft Orchestrator 2012, and I keep getting this error

Activities\RunScript\w0vjlke0.0.js(8,14) : error JS1015: Unterminated string constant

It would be greatly appreciated if you could help me as I can't seem to find out what's causing it.

I guess this would be a rubber ducky debug ^_^

```
        //Questions and answers will be ordered in two separated arrays
        var questions = new Array();
        var answers = new Array();
        //Your data
        var myData = '\`d.T.~Ed/{8DFD771C-13FA-40D4-84AE-8ECD056BCC2D}.UserInput\`d.T.~Ed/';
        //Regex goes here
        var regex=/\"(.*?)\"/g;
        var match = regex.exec(myData);
        var i = 1;
        var pos = 0;
        //Loop for all questions and answers, avoiding the type="string" attribute
while (match != null) {
    pos = i % 3;
    switch(pos){
        case 1: questions[questions.length] = match[1]; break;
        case 2: answers[answers.length] = match[1]; break;
    }
    i++;
    match = regex.exec(myData);
    }
    //Check all questions and answers are at their correct positions
    //Loop to grab all data and input the html fields to format into table
    var counter='';
    var objectnumber=(i-5);
    objectnumber = objectnumber/2;
    counter=0;
    var html1q='<tr><td>';
    var html2q='</td><td>';
    var html3q='</td></tr>';
    var realtext='';
    while (objectnumber != counter) {
       realtext += html1q + questions[counter] + html2q + answers[counter] + html3q;
        counter++;
    }
    output=realtext;
```

Okay thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe missing quotes around

```
var regex=/\"(.*?)\"/g;
```

??

I don't speak jscript, but that doesn't look right and it jumped out at me...

Comment: Regular expressions in JavaScript are more like Perl than PHP -- you don't need to write them as a string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions